# 553 5.1.3 The recipient address is not a valid RFC-5321 address

Tags: email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

When sending bulk emails I was receiving several error messages that said:

```
553 5.1.3 The recipient address <john@example.com > is not a valid RFC-5321 address.
```

The format of the email addresses looked completely valid so I couldn't figure out at first why these messages weren't being delivered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon further inspection, I noticed that the recipient email addresses for each of the failed messages had a single space on the end.  It's not as hard to see in the example I provided above, but the error report I was viewing had smaller font and would sometimes put a line break where the space was, so it wasn't as obvious.  By the way, I was using the SendGrid API to send these emails, but I don't think that the issue would be unique to using SendGrid.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using node.js API for sending emails to people, you just need to add `.trimRight()` to your recipients email address in your API, so in this way the white space will be removed and you can successfully send your email. :)

Comment: You probably just want a `.trim()`. Later you could end up with a space on the left too... that way it's fixed for longer term.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Django Restful Api and my mistake was, when registering the users, I had interchanged the email field with the username field. So the Smtp server was using the username as the email address used to send the verification emails. I corrected that interchanged the fields correctly and it worked.